# R missing after import the Sherlock action bar android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-resources

I was creating my project using android 4.4, now I want to build it with android 2.3.3.
I got some errors in my style.xml that theme not supported.

To resolve this error I have imported the Sherlock Action Bar library. Now my style.xml error is resolved but I now get an error `'R' is missing from project`
I have cleaned the project but it is not resolved.

Does anyone know how can I resolve this issue ?

My log cat is

```
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values\styles.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:backgroundStacked'.
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values\styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values\styles.xml:18: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarStyle'.
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values\styles.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:alertDialogTheme'.
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values\styles.xml:77: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:buttonBarButtonStyle'.
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values\styles.xml:73: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowMinWidthMajor'.
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values\styles.xml:74: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowMinWidthMinor'.
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2014-07-21 06:59:00 - PingMyAndroid] C:\Users\Bilal Khalid\android_development\PingMyAndroid\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'
.
```

Comment: Does your project has support-v4 library in `libs` folder?

Comment: yes i have added the v4 as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you add ABS as a library to your project? The R file will not generate is there is an error in the xml from what i've experienced.

If you haven't added ABS as a library follow:

Right-click project in package explorer->Properties->Android->Under library click Add->Select ABS->Click ok-> should be good to go after that.

Comment: i have added the sherloack library in my project from properties->android->add but it doesn't work.